# Process text file - Extract data starting with number

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, csv

I have a list of contact information I need to process in `.txt` format seperated by `,` . We only want to keep SIC codes that start with `65` which is real estate.

The command should only check for the correct field for data that starts with 65.

Please keep in mind that the number wont always be `6531`, it just has to start with `65` (6521 6555 6587 for example would be something we would also want to keep)

```
2,J,John Foraste Photography,atlanticinn@biri.com,68 Middle Hwy,Barrington,RI,2806, , ,733511,Photographic Engineering,atlanticinn.com
3,X,Xerox Corp,danielle_cook@xeroxscanners.com,10 Orms St # 420,Providence,RI,02904-7815,5594547871,4012763242,504403,Copying & Duplicating Machines & Supls,www.xerox.com
4,S,St Sahag & St Mesrob Armenian,h.ghajanian@osjl.com,70 Jefferson St,Providence,RI,02908-4923,4012722832,4012727712,866107,Churches,www.stsahmes.org
13,C,Century 21 Access America,damonray@mail.com,1025 Tiogue Ave,Coventry,RI,02816-6100,4018282100, ,6531,Real Estate, 
14,B,Baxter's Showroom,rbaxters@aol.com,Null,Warwick,RI,0,4017398222,4017397058,594409,Jewelers,baxtersjewelry.com^^majorfindings.com^^robertbaxter.com^^san
17,R,Re/Max South County,ereadey@yahoo.com,56 Wells Street,Westerly,RI,2891,4015962067, ,6531,Real Estate, 
19,L,Lyn Reale - Block Island Realty,saintwolfe@computer.org,215Chapelstreet,Block Island,RI,2807,4012534311, ,653118,Real Estate,stmichaelsbristolri.org
21,R,Re/Max South County,apage@remax.net,56 Wells Street,Westerly,RI,2891,4015962067, ,6531,Real Estate, 
22,V,Vns Home Health Svc,george@vnshomehealth.org,14 Woodruff Ave # 7,Narragansett,RI,02882-3467,4017882253,4017820500,808201,Home Health Service,
```

After processing the list should be

```
13,C,Century 21 Access America,damonray@mail.com,1025 Tiogue Ave,Coventry,RI,02816-6100,4018282100, ,6531,Real Estate, 
17,R,Re/Max South County,ereadey@yahoo.com,56 Wells Street,Westerly,RI,2891,4015962067, ,6531,Real Estate, 
19,L,Lyn Reale - Block Island Realty,saintwolfe@computer.org,215Chapelstreet,Block Island,RI,2807,4012534311, ,653118,Real Estate,stmichaelsbristolri.org
21,R,Re/Max South County,apage@remax.net,56 Wells Street,Westerly,RI,2891,4015962067, ,6531,Real Estate,
```

Comment: Does your data have a header row?

Comment: No we removed it. Just text separated by , in .txt

Comment: You should not post data like this publicly. I hope that this is dummy examples, but it doesn't look like it

Comment: Why not `Lyn reale` with `653118`?

Comment: @Fiximan, looks like that data is already public.

Comment: `awk -F, '$11 ~ /^65/'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `awk`

```
awk -F, '{if ( $11 ~ /^65/ ) print $0}' file
```

explanation: use comma as field separator `-F,` , check if column 11 starts (`^`) with 65 `if ( $11 ~ /^65/ )`, if so print whole line `print $0`

Comment: Thanks, could you also give me the command to do this for SIC codes starting with 65 and 64? Would I just do /^64/^65/ ?

Comment: an "OR" in the regex would be `|`, i.e. `/^65|^64/`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <> ) {
    print if (split /,/)[10] =~ m/^65/;
}
```

Can one liner it if you like as:

```
perl -ne 'print if (split /,/)[10] =~ m/^65/;' yourfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/,65[0-9]*,Real Estate/! d' file.txt
```